# Error in login to asp.net web site using membership class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I had wrote a web site using asp.net mvc3 and used Membership class for user management.
everything work fine on my localhost server in VS2010 but when I deploy that to server I got some times following error:

```
    Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/23/2011 3:30:31 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/23/2011 10:30:31 PM 
Event ID: 5afe87171ad743d39bf87e29f8501615 
Event sequence: 7785 
Event occurrence: 49 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-3-129559136991646761 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bandarMVC\ 
    Machine name: BANDARPAYANE 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2612 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\MVC 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at BandarMVC.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in C:\Users\Javad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BandarMVC\BandarMVC\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://10.1.1.90/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/ 
    Request path: /Account/LogOn 
    User host address: 10.1.1.90 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\MVC 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 26 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\MVC 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at BandarMVC.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in C:\Users\Javad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BandarMVC\BandarMVC\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

does anyone one knows reason of this error and solution of that?

the following code throws this exception:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        BuildMenu();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    ------->  if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))   <----------------
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "نام کاربر و یا شناسه عبور صحیح نمی باشد");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you put up the code that is throwing this error?

Comment: I have update the question and put the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the database you are connecting to when you deployed your application was created with some older version of the .NET Framework [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) utility. Try [creating and configuring the membership database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) with the same version of `aspnet_regsql` you used locally. Or maybe locally you simply used SQL Express and the `~/App_Data` folder.

Comment: I have used .NET Framework v4.0.30319 in both server and In localhost I use SQLEXPRESS SERVER 2008 R2 but in localhost SQLEXPRESS 2008.what should I do?
I have to emphasis that I got that error seldom.

Comment: Compare the table structure in both databases. You want to compare the aspnet_Membership table first.